# Loop through a List of an object and build a Map using Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of ElementCharacteristic. I want to loop through this list and build a Map<String,String>. How to do this in Java Stream API?

```
public Map<String,String> getMap(List<ElementCharacteristic> inputList) {
    Map<String,String> outPutMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(ElementCharacteristic ele : inputList) {
        outPutMap.put(ele.getCharacteristic(),ele.getFeature());
    }
    return outPutMap;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a classic `Collectors.toMap()` use case.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use this code:

```
Map<String, String> outPutMap = new HashMap<>();
inputList.stream()
    .map(p->outPutMap.put(p.getCharacteristic(), p.getFeature()));
```

or this one:

```
Map<String,String> outPutMap = inputList .stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(p-> p.getCharacteristic(), p-> p.getFeature()));
```

Comment: `map()` does nothing without a terminal operation. You could call for `Stream.forEach()`, but then you might as well call `List.forEach()`, which is roughly equivalent to what OP already posted. The second snippet is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` function to achieve that:

```
public Map<String,String> getMap(List<ElementCharacteristic> inputList) {
    return inputList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ElementCharacteristic::getCharacteristic, ElementCharacteristic::getFeature));
}
```